# get the length of div without img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the length of the `div` mentioned in the below codes :

```
<div id="txt">Hello <img src="..."> <b>Emoji</b> </div>
```

I use these `jquery` codes (Count of all characters including `img` tags):

```
var mylength= $("#txt").html().length;
```

The image is an emoji that must be counted 2. So instead of each `img` , the count must be 2 not the real length. How can I do this?

**NOTE:** It must count the other tags as they are (ex: `<b>A</b>` is 8). Only `img` tags must be counted 2.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rpknphym/1/

Comment: Domelem.textContent.length ?

Comment: `var mylength= $("#txt").html().length - $("#txt>img").html().length + 2;`

Comment: Try to clone the div to a variable, remove img tag from the variable and get the length you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Remove the img tag(s) and  add the img tag(s) length in the remaining html length

```js
var copy= $("#txt").clone();
var count = $(copy).find("img").length;
$(copy).find("img").remove();
// it must be 21 = 12 (text chars) + 7 (b tag) + 2 (img tag)
console.log(copy.html().length + count * 2); // img tag counts for 2
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="txt">Hello<img src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.1.4/assets/png/1f61b.png"> <b>Emoji</b> </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Save the HTML as a variable:

```
var html=$('#text').html();
```

Then, replace all image tags with something 2 characters long

```
html = html.replace(/<img\ssrc\="[a-zA-Z\/:\.0-9\?\&\=\-_]+">/g,'im');
```

Then you can find the length of it with

```
var len=html.length;
```

```js
var html = $('#text').html();

html = html.replace(/<img\ssrc\="[a-zA-Z\/:\.0-9\?\&\=\-_]+">/g, 'im');
var len = html.length;
$('#text').text(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">
  <img src="/favicon.ico">
  <img src="http://www.google.com/favicon.ico">hello world
  <h1>big text</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This accounts for multiple img tags.

```
var mylength = $("#txt").html().length; 
$("img","#txt").each(function() { mylength -= this.outerHTML.length - 2;});
```

[Your fiddle, forked.](https://jsfiddle.net/4ubketdm/2/)